# Matrix can be orthogonally diagonalized iff its eigenvectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Could anyone make the proof more obvious for me? The author should prove it in both directions, i.e. if a matrix can be orthogonally diagonalized, then its eigenvectors are linearly independent. And if its eigenvectors are linearly independent, then the matrix can be orthogonally diagonalized. But I can only see the second part here.

How do we know that $AE=ED$ is true? Because we've assumed that matrix $A$ has independent eigenvectors and this equality is true by definition, right?

---

[image]

Comment: Obviously, a matrix with independent eigenvectors can *not* be diaonalized orthogonally in general.

Comment: Source: page 10, Appendix A, 4) http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1100v1.pdf So point 4 is completely wrong?

Comment: No, 4) is the well known spectral theorem (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Comment: But a part of the proof given there is wrong. That's what two people said already.

Comment: There is a mistake. It should read "a matrix can be diagonalized if and only if there is a basis of eigenvectors. In the second part of the proof, we see that a symmetric matrix has the special property that all of its eigenvectors are orthogonal." Which solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. If I did my calculations right, the eigenvectors of 
$$\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \\  \end{matrix} \right)$$
are $(1,0)$ (with eigenvalue $1$) and $(1,1)$ (with eigenvalue $2$). They are linearly independent. Yet the matrix cannot be orthogonally diagonalized. To orthogonally diagonalize is to find a full set of orthogonal eigenspaces. A $2 \times 2$ matrix can have at most two eigenspaces. We've found them both, and they are not orthogonal.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1100v1.pdf So point 4 is completely wrong? (page 10)